# Java serial comm - IllegatStateException - port is closed

Tags: java, serial-port

I have some existing device driver software I'm working with in Java that uses JavaCOMM for serial I/O.  I saw it throw an exception yesterday where it thew an IllegalStateException - port is closed from inside the public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent event) callback method.  I did not see any log messages that the application had explicity closed the port.  Can anyone think of why I'd be seeing this error?

Thank you.
Sean

Answer (score 1):

I was never able to get JavaCOMM working. I ended up using [serialio.jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3049/how-do-i-configure-and-communicate-with-a-serial-port/24078#24078).

Comment: JavaCOMM is a hassle to set up, getting all the files in the right directory etc., but I have a lot of legacy code that uses it so I'm stuck with it for now.  I will check out serialio.jar however :)